# Where do I find proguard.cfg in my project?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I want to enable the `ProGuard` for my application and in this documentation [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) it says that the `proguard.cfg`, where I have to modify something, is automatically generated. But if I look in my project folder I only see a `proguard-project.txt` file but I dont see the `proguard.cfg` which I need.

How can I get this proguard.cfg? Or was I'm doing wrong?

Please guid me to this file.

Comment: The proguard-project.txt is a project specific, there is another file uner ANDROID_SDK/tool/proguard/proguard-android.txt or ANDROID_SDK/tool/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt